# Will wearing skill fortifying items to boost my skill above 100 stop that skill from levelling up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For example, if my one-handed skill is at 90, and I use an enchanted ring to boost that skill to 105, then go bashing away at Falmer for a while, will the skill level bar continue to fill, or will it stay at 90 until I unequip the ring?

Answer (score 7):

No it will not.

Boosts that increase your skills shown level, only increases the benefits that you receive.

You will still level at the same rate that you'd level if you weren't wearing the ring.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't stop accumulating xp for that skill. I don't see a reason why there should be a penalty for wearing a fortify one-handed ring? Maybe it accumlate a bit slower xp? Most likely the changes in time is more important then the absolute skill lvl. A fortify one-handed just boost the damage not the xp.

Comment: I guess one-handed was a bad example. thanks for the prompt response :)